# PHP data not properly entering mySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that is running on a frontend. The frontend takes data and inputs it into a SQL DB. For the most part it's running fine, however there are certain characters that cause the entry to be blank in the DB. So far it seems like |, / and \ characters cause the entry to be blank. Below is my PHP code to insert the data into a SQL DB. I'm guess it's beacuse it's not sanitizing properly but I can't figure out why.

```
if (!empty($_POST['do'])) {
    switch ($_POST['do']) {
        case 'add':
             if (empty($_POST['quote'])) {
                 break;
             }
             $quote = htmlspecialchars($_POST['quote']);
             $quote = str_replace("  ", "&nbsp;&nbsp;", $quote);
             $quote = nl2br($quote);
             if (ini_get("magic_quotes_runtime") or ini_get("magic_quotes_gpc")) {
                  $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$_qdbs['tpfx']."queue (id,quote) VALUES ('NULL', '".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($quote))."')";
             } else {
                  $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$_qdbs['tpfx']."queue (id,quote) VALUES ('NULL', '".mysql_real_escape_string($quote)."')";
             }
             $r = $db->_sql($sql);
             print($tpl->fetch($tpl->tdir.'layout_header.tpl'));
             print($tpl->fetch($tpl->tdir.'quote_added.tpl'));
             print($tpl->fetch($tpl->tdir.'layout_footer.tpl'));
             break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't put `NULL` in quotes if you want it to auto-increment the `id` column. Either use `NULL` unquoted, or leave out the column entirely in the `INSERT`.

Comment: It would be best if you switched to an API that provides prepared statements, either PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Are you getting any errors from SQL when it fails? You need to add error checking -- print `mysql_error()` when the query fails.

Comment: I do want it to autoincrement. I'm not getting any errors - it creates the entry in the SQL DB, it's just blank (no data). The id increments and a new row is created.

Comment: It sounds like `mysql_real_escape_string` is getting an error and returning `false`, which ends up being a null string when concatenated. I'm not sure what would cause that, though.